# Improving combine txt code through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have below VBA code that divided for tWo. First part of the code collect data from file directory and paste it on excel file (file name, path & modified date).

Second part of the code collect all txt file in the folder and marge them to one list in the same sheet.

I tried to improve my code to support more than one folder source and to combine both codes to one ( I joined two different codes to one) but I failed to do it. Any idea how to modified it?

Thanks,

Code:

```
Sub list()

'adding file name, path & last modify date

  Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim FileItem As Scripting.File

    SourceFolderName = "\\HA04HUCM0002\TestLog\LOT\avi_tests"

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    Range("c2:e2") = Array("text file", "path", "Date Last Modified")

    i = 3
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        Cells(i, 3) = FileItem.Name
        Cells(i, 4) = FileItem
        Cells(i, 5) = FileItem.DateLastModified
        i = i + 1
    Next FileItem

    Set FSO = Nothing
'combain txt data into one sheet
 Dim xSht As Worksheet
 Dim xWb As Workbook
 Dim xStrPath As String
 Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
 Dim xFile As String
 On Error GoTo ErrHandler
 Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
 xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
 If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
 xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
 End If
 If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
 Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 If MsgBox("Clear the existing sheet before importing?", vbYesNo, "Kutools for Excel") = vbYes Then xSht.UsedRange.Clear
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "" & "*.txt")

 Do While xFile <> ""
 Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & "" & xFile)
 Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
 Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
 ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
 xWb.Close False
 xFile = Dir
 Loop
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
 MsgBox "no txt files ", , "Kutools for Excel"

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly did you fail to do? What were the errors you encountered?

Comment: I tried to add more folders paths ( I have several but I success to run use only one).

Comment: As for text file - I guess, you just need to generate text file and open it in Excel?

Comment: Yes but I want to add more files from different folders. in addition if I will have to filter txt file according to date (2nd code) I will not need the first one, I failed to do that till now.

Answer (score 0):

To process another folder, simply ask the User if they want to run the code again.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If MsgBox("Do you want to process  another folder?", vbYesNoCancel, "Kutools for Excel") = vbYes Then
    Call list
End If
```

Comment: Thanks It will close one item for me. Any idea how can I filter data to take only files from the last 7 days?

Comment: This article uses VB Script [Reading and Altering File Attributes](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/112600-1.shtml) to get the file info bu it is still relavent.